# JSF 2 navigation always from root folder

Tags: jsf-2, navigation

I have a JSF 2 application with the following xhtml structure:

--webapp
  --index.xhtml
  --folder1
    --targetPage.xhtml
  --folder2
    --otherPage.xhtml

I have a managed bean called TargetPageBean with the following method:

```
public String navigateToTargetPage() {

    if( isOnIndexPage() ) {
        return "folder1/targetPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    } else {
        return "targetPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

This would work fine in these two cases:

- I navigate just from the index page to the target page
- I am already on the target page and I navigate to this page again

But this approach is pretty bad because my tree strcuture could be deeper and I could want to move to the target page from nearly everywhere. Can I tell JSF that it should always redirect from the "root" so that I just have to return `folder1/targetPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true`? (I do not want to use the explicit navigation via the faces-config file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use redirect with full request path:

```
getFacesContext().getExternalContext().redirect(getRequest().getContextPath() +
    "/page.jsf?" + Constants.CONSTANT_NAME + "=" + bean.getSomeValue());
```

where

```
protected HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    return (HttpServletRequest) getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getRequest();
}
protected FacesContext getFacesContext() {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
}
```