# JSF redirect from Bean

Tags: jsf, redirect

I try following

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .redirect("/common/pageNotFound.jsf");
```

But it´s not the correct result. Because the the method will redirect to:

> http:// localhost :8080/common/pageNotFound.jsf

But I want to > http:// localhost:8080/app/common/pageNotFound.jsf

How can I do this?

Comment: .redirect("common/pageNotFound.jsf")?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174510/jsf-2-navigation-always-from-root-folder/22175098#22175098) if it good for you